# My recursive function (javascript) always return false, even when it's true

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I have an issue with a recursive function. It always return false, even when it's true.

I have the following array with names :

```
const tableaux = ["Nico","Luc","Paul","Jean","Samy",
"Domi","Cricri","André","Valérie","Mouss","Léon",
"Lionnel","Jacques","Marie","Vanessa","Mohammed","Fatou"];
```

And here is my function :

```
tableaux.sort(); 

const binarySearch = (array, nameToFind, start, end) => { 
    
    if(start > end) {
        return false;
    }

    let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2); 
    
    if(mid === nameToFind) {
        return true;
    }

    if(nameToFind < tableaux[mid]) {
        return binarySearch(array, nameToFind, start, mid - 1); 
    } else {
        return binarySearch(array, nameToFind, mid + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Then when i use a name that is in my array, it still return false :

```
let test = binarySearch(tableaux, 'Marie', 1, 17);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: `mid` is an index, so `mid == nameToFind` will never be true.

Comment: `if(mid === nameToFind)`, `mid` is a number

Comment: This is where debugging with console comes in handy to see why things are not working. If conditions are not working for me I tend to do `console.log(mid, nameToFind, mid===nameToFind); if(mid === nameToFind) {` Doing this you would have seen the problem.

Comment: A strong suggestion: don't use `tableaux[mid]` but rather `array[mid]`.  This will make your function more generally useful and easier to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the following:

```
let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2); 

if (mid === nameToFind) {
  return true;
}
```

In this, you assign `mid` a number (the index you're looking for), and then compare that directly with `nameToFind`. You just need to compare against the item at the index `mid` instead:

```
let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2); 

if (array[mid] === nameToFind) {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Oh right I used `tableaux[mid]` and it's now working, cheers !